# wrong java version in heroku

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, java-9

I've created a spring boot app and would like to run it on [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).
My app is compiled using java 9.

As I'm deploying it to heroku using the [CLI plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files#using-the-heroku-deploy-cli-plugin) I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: io/safeblocks/firewall/FirewallApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Clearly this means java versions mismatch. I added the `system.properties` file to my resources folder with the property `java.runtime.version=9` [as explained](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1263) but still getting the same error.

As I run the command `heroku run java -version --app myApp`  I'm getting:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_171-heroku"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-heroku-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

So it seems heroku is still not picking up the required java version.
Any ideas?

Comment: Seems something incorrect related to the configuration. What java version does your `mvn -v` read? Also, did heroku install JDK9 along with JDK8 as well? e.g. as the link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#deploy-the-app read *"Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you added the `system.properties` file to your resources folder, I did the same mistake. The file `system.properties` must be placed under the root folder of your project.

The content of your file is correct:
`java.runtime.version=9`

After you moved the file to the root folder, commit your changes and do:
`git push heroku master`

Everything should be fine then.